Strange Excel 365 font behavior while editing in cell after Aptos update
My Microsoft 365 installation just got updated to use the new Aptos fonts. Excel is now using Aptos Narrow (11 pt) as its default font.  This is not a question about the merits, or lack thereof, of Aptos, nor am I looking for opinions on whether one font is better than the other.
Since the update happened, I've seen a strange issue:
When I double click on a cell to edit it in place, the font in the cell slightly changes.  The size changes, the spacing/kerning becomes funky, and it just looks weird.  After editing is done the cell displays normally.
This only appears to happen when the cell is formatted with the default Aptos Narrow.  I tried regular Aptos, Calibri, and some fancier fonts and none of them have that issue; the text format in the cell remains consistent while editing in the cell.
Example: notice in the screen capture below.  Both cells have identical text with Aptos Narrow (11 pt).  The top cell is being edited in place, which should retain formatting.  Yet in the cell getting edited the font slightly grew, and the spacing is all weird ('h' is shifted closer to the 'i' than the 'T', for instance).

Looking for ideas/suggestions on how to fix this or confirmation from others that this is a bug/feature that has been observed in other systems.  While this happened with the update to Aptos Narrow I don't consider it to be related to the look or feel of the font. It could be due to some error in the underlying design of the font, I suppose.
Yes, I'm aware that I could revert the default template to Calibri.   However, since it is a managed system, it is likely to reset to the new default on further updates.

This is a matter of opinion. If you don't like a font, don't use it. There are a plethora of others. Selecting a font takes only a second in a document, and perhaps a minute to change in the doc template.

@DrMoishePippik - I respectfully disagree.  As I stated in my question this is NOT about discussing the merits of Aptos (that would indeed be a matter of opinion).  I have a particular issue in that one font, which happens to be a new font, behaves in a manner seems unexpected.  Namely its formatting changes while being edited in-cell.  I will edit the question to try make that even clearer.

This is an interesting problem, but I would guess that you have two options and only one of them is effective today: Change the font. The other solution is to report this as a bug to Microsoft using the feedback tool in Office.

I have been unable to reproduce this issue on my Office 365 installation running 17628.20144 which was released on June 19th. I also see no mention of the font change with the release of that build. In fact the only mention of Aptos this entire year was back in February with regards to a Word bug fix. What build are you running I checked Release and Beta there wasn’t a build released today

Seconding that this is not an opinion and shouldn't have been closed as such. But also the comment about reporting this as a bug to Microsoft is probably correct as the only thing we can do about it.
